# Prove that if $m<n$ then $S$ does not generate $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $K$ such that $dim V=n$ and let $S\subseteq V$ such that $|S|=m$. Prove that if $m<n$ then $S$ does not generate $V$

Let $S=${$s_1,...,s_m$}. Suppose that $S$ generates $V$. Then every vector $v\in V$ is of the form $v=\sum_{k=1}^{m}\alpha_ks_k$, $\alpha_k\in K$. Let $B=${$b_1,...,b_n$} be a basis of $V$ then $v=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\beta_kb_k$, $\beta_k\in K$; we have that:

$$v=\sum_{k=1}^{m}\alpha_ks_k=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\beta_kb_k$$ but then this can´t happen because $m<n$, Is this a valid argument?

Comment: What is your definition of "dimension of vector space"?

Comment: Not quite.  Use the fact that we can write
$$
\beta_j = \sum_{k=1}^m \alpha_k^{(j)} s_k
$$
and use this to conclude that $B$ is not a linearly independent set.

Comment: @Nameless ? $\;S\;$ is a *set* of $\;m\;,\;\;m<n\;$ vectors. It may or may not generate $\;V\;$ . What has this to do with it being or not a subspace?